# How to translate text field content in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a text field that a user can insert any text in it ,check box for 3 languages ,a user can choose the language he want then click on button translate
he will get the translated text in another text field
if there is a way to do that ?

Comment: I'd use something that offers ~120 languages and works quite well. As you said - you put any text into one *field* and have it translated to any of mentioned 120 languages. Here: https://translate.google.com/ In other words, I wouldn't involve Apex into it.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Do *what*? Go to that site and translate anything you want to any language offered.

Comment: I want to do that in apex something like google translate  Is this available to be done?

Comment: Probably; you'd have to have as many "dictionaries" as languages you want to offer - 3, in your case. Imagine number of words your application should be able to translate! Do you have such data? Because, it would be pretty much useless if you can translate only "dog", "cat" and "cow". Maybe you can download such dictionaries, can't tell (nor did I search for them). That's why I think that it is simpler to use what already works, and works well - Google translator. What you could do in an easy manner is to put a **link** to it onto your Apex page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this:
APEX JTL Item Plugin
https://github.com/rimblas/jtlitem

> An Oracle APEX Item plugin for storing multi-language translations
> (MLS) in a JSON column. Now with IG support!
>
> This plugin allows you to store multiple language translations on a
> single table column. Optionally, the user can popup a dialog and edit
> all the available translations.